# Como usar apenas o Editor de interface do Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Eu programo pra `Android` com `Xamarin` no `Visual Studio`, mas não curto nada o editor de design dele, tem como eu usar só o editor do `Android Studio` quando eu precisar? Eu mudei a extensão do design de `.axml` pra `.xml` e abri no `Android Studio`, consegui abrir, mas não tem as dicas na hora de digitar e nem tem o design visual, que era o que eu queria pra ver se está saindo tudo bem. Eu posso abrir um projeto vazio e copiar meu design lá, mas projeto demora pra abrir no `Android Studio` então eu perderia muito tempo. Mas então, tem algum meio de fazer isso?

Comment: No Android Studio pode editar o layout só no modo `xml` sem utilizar o modo visual, e mesmo no modo `xml` tem um preview ao lado para ver como está a sair

Comment: até se você não estiver com um projeto aberto? sendo só abrir um `xml` (o design) mesmo?

Comment: Não. Tem de ter o IDE aberto claro.

Comment: Ah, entendo, eu estava procurando um meio de usar apenas o editor `xml`, mesmo tento o IDE aberto, só não precisar abrir um projeto pra fazer isso, acho que irei ficar no do Visual Studio mesmo e quando precisar visualizar ou depuro ou abro um projeto no Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Eu mudei a extensão do design de .axml pra .xml e abri no Android Studio, consegui abrir, mas não tem as dicas na hora de digitar e nem
>   tem o design visual, que era o que eu queria pra ver se está saindo
>   tudo bem"*

O autocomplete não dá as dicas porque ele precisa de um projeto que contenha o "gradle" do aplicativo com as bibliotecas e referências, são eles que fazem aparecer as dicas e o preview da tela.

Você atualizou o VS e as extensões do Xamarin? A Microsoft atualizou e a ferramenta está melhor do que antes.

Comment: Estou com o VS 2017, vou ver se há alguma atualização e ver se melhora, de qualquer maneira, obrigado, se a atualização melhorar marco como respondido, se não, eu continuo usando o Android Studio quando precisar mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Para que um arquivo(layout) **xml** seja aberto no editor de *layouts* do Android Studio ele tem de estar dentro da pasta `res/layout` do projecto.

É um "pouco esquisito" o que quer, no entanto pode fazer o seguinte:

- Crie um projecto para esse efeito e mantenha-o aberto.
- No explorador do Windows clique, com o botão direito do rato, no arquivo que quer editar e escolha `Copiar`.
- Volte ao Android Studio, clique, com o botão direito do rato, na pasta `res/layout` e escolha `Paste`.
- Na janela que abre, altere a extensão para `xml`.

O arquivo é aberto numa nova aba, permitindo ser editado no editor de *layouts*.

Note que se o *layout* referenciar outros *resources* eles terão de estar nas respectivas pastas `res/xxx`.

Comment: Mas precisa de um projeto aberto no Android Studio para isso? eu queria apenas o editor de layouts, meio que "standalone", porque abrir o Android Studio e o Visual Studio ao mesmo tempo exigiria um pouco mais do meu pc, sem contar que o Android Studio demora um pouco para abrir. Mas se não tiver um meio de fazer isso posso ficar no editor de xml do Visual Studio mesmo, não é nada que possa comprometer a programação, só iria me ajudar mais já que o visualizador de design dele demora pra abrir aqui, a indentação não é tão boa e nem as dicas

Comment: *"Mas precisa de um projeto aberto no Android Studio para isso?"*: Sim, que eu saiba não há outro modo. *"... o Android Studio demora um pouco para abrir"*: Só terá de o abrir uma vez e mantê-lo aberto.

Comment: entendo, mas manter ele aberto junto ao Visual Studio faria meu pc ficar meio lento, acho que vou me contentar com o editor do Visual Studio mesmo, obrigado de qualquer maneira